# Android USB driver for Xperia X10a

Tags: android

I've been trying for a couple hours now, and have hit all of the sites Google found, but i cannot get the Android USB driver on my XP box to talk to my new Xperia X10a. I found the lines that some kind soul posted, and has been syndicated repeated, but they don't work for me. The idea is to add them to the `Google.NTx86` and `Google.NTamd64` sections of the `android_winusb.inf` file:

```
;Xperia X10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_E12E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_E12E&MI_01
```

I tried a number of variations of the first line, including `Sony Ericsson X10a`, which is what XP shows me in both the "found new hardware" wizard and the device manager, but no luck. The result is always the same. Here are my steps:

- Plug in the phone via USB
- "found new hardware wizard" appears
- Choose "No, not this time" and "next"
- Choose "Install from a list or specific location..." and "next"
- Choose "Search for best driver...", check "Include this location...", and browse for the "usb_driver" folder in the Android SDK installation. Click "next"

It does a quick search and then says "Cannot install this hardware", "... because the wizard cannot find the necessary software".

I've tried more things that i can recall now, including deleting registry entries, but it just won't work. Any help would be appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. (BTW, the original android_winusb.inf information came from user Kirrrilka on the android dev google group, so many thanks to him.)

The proper entries in the android_winusb.inf for the xperia x10a phone are as follows:

```
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_D12E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_D12E&MI_01
```

I.e. the PID is "D12E" instead of "E12E". I found this information by going to the XP Device Manager (My Computer -> Properties -> Hardware -> Device Manager), finding the device (i don't recall what it was called there before, but it had a big yellow question mark icon), right-clicking for properties, details tab, and looking at the "device instance id". I hope this information helps other with new phones that are not yet supported.

Regards,
m@

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the X10, but with my Moto Droid, there's no driver. You just plug it in, and (IMPORTANT), "mount" the phone from the notification menu, and then it shows up as a removable drive. Without mounting, it doesn't do anything but charge.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried it again making sure the phone was mounted, and even tried installing some SE software, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `android_winusb.inf` with Notepad.
2. Make sure you add device codes under proper section. There are `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]` - chose one that corresponds to your system.
3. Now adding these codes should work:

   ```
   %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_D12E
   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_D12E&MI_01
   ```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, using the info above from mlohbihler about where to get the device ID on XP, the correct entries for a MyTouch 3g Slide turn out to be:

```
; MyTouch 3g Slide
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0E03
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0E03&MI_01
```

And for the nexus s usb hardware,

```
; nexus s
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest driver there is no android_winusb.inf but adding the same lines to sa0101usb.inf under the heading SEMC.NTx86 works.