# Android Development on Xperia arc S

Tags: android, eclipse

Similar to [Android USB driver for Xperia X10a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656595/android-usb-driver-for-xperia-x10a)

How do I install the driver for Xperia arc S?

The driver I am using is from this page: [Sony Ericsson driver downloads](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/sonyericssonxperiaarcxperianeoxperiaplaydrivers?cc=gb&lc=en)

I have tried adding the following to sa0102rndis.inf

```
[SEMC.NTx86]
%SingleAdbInterface%        = RNDIS.NT.5.1, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_014F
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = RNDIS.NT.5.1, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_014F&MI_01
```

With or without these lines I get the error *This device cannot start. (Code 10)*

I would appreciate any help with this as it would be nice to not have to copy the APK every time I need to test.

Comment: Several possible reasons for this, but beforehand, did you turn on USB Debug Mode on your phone?

Comment: I tried with USB Debug Mode turned on and just now with it turned off. When it is on the Sony Ericsson PC Companion tries to configure the phone at the same time but fails.

Comment: As Wong said try to turn the USB Debug Mode & try if you are working in windows system check the device manager whether any software needs to be updated.If so probably update the usb driver for the device & see...

Comment: I should have mentioned I am doing this on Windows XP.

Comment: Can you add the device manager screenshot here.

Comment: Hey check this [one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656595/android-usb-driver-for-xperia-x10a

Comment: Can you do development on Linux? You don’t need special USB drivers there.

Comment: I think it will have to be Linux in the short term. Thanks guys.

@Karthik Before and after trying to install the driver: [screen 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/devices2.png/) [screen2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/devices.png/)

Answer (score 1):

@ JayBird I came across this being discussed in one of a forum,please check [this link](http://talk.sonyericsson.com/thread/14565).Hope this help.

Try this,quoted from the forum

The system give me a code 10 error when connect to pc companion thru USB

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/arcz.jpg/

The only thing that work is, close pc companion, unmount the sd card(settings>storage>), than connect the phone with the usb cable, than open the pc companion,

I hope there is a better solution for this insue!!!

Comment: The answer is to set USB connection mode to Mass storage mode. Thanks for your help!